# Enable / disable menu items using session in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, session

```
If Session IsNot Nothing And Session("Admin") = "ftghgy" Then

Dim rptMenuItem As MenuItem = Menu1.FindItem("Home")

rptMenuItem.Selectable = True

Label9.Text = ("Welcome")

 Else
Label9.Text = ("Welcome " + "" + Session("UserName").ToString)

endif
```

I am getting this error...

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line "rptMenuItem.Selectable = True"
```

I and am not using a master page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then probably this line is returning null value :

```
Menu1.FindItem("Home")
```

Meaning that an item with id "Home" couldn't be found in your Menu1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be integer `Menu1.FindItem(Type)`